# Set different timezone for each deployable in tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, timezone

I have a web project which creates 2 separate deployables(.war files). I deployed both in single tomcat, and when I change the JVM timezone in a beanFactoryPostProcessor of fist deployable, it also get reflected in second deployable also.

I have few questions around it

1. Is this the normal behavior
2. If I want to set separate timezone for each deployable how would I do it
3. Can we set separate timezone for different Spring Context also
4. Are different war files run in separate JVM instance or same JVM in a tomcat

Comment: My earlier understand was that for each deployable, tomcat maintain separate system properties. And same for the spring context, separe system properties are maintained. So doing some change in in one context or deployable will be scoped in it only

Comment: If you are using Spring why are you setting the system timezone? Relying on the system timezone is fragile and errorprone, don't do it. Furthermore, Tomcat does **not** maintain separate system properties per application, how could it - they are **system** properties. Whether it maintains separate Spring contexts is entirely up to you.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/FixedLocaleResolver.html

Comment: My purpose was to make JVM timezone to UTC, so that every calculation I do will work on UTC. 
Why system timezone is errorprone?

Comment: If you think you need the system timezone for that you don't understand how to use Java date/time I'm afraid. You should always be explicit about your timezone when needed. But to do calculations in UTC just use `Instant`. It's errorprone for exactly the reason you found - some clever person might decide to `System.setProperty` in a library because want "_every calculation [they] do [to] work on UTC_", then they forget to set it back. Now suddenly your system timezone has changed. Don't even get me started on threading.

Comment: Thanks @BoristheSpider that really helpful, I will make my code independent of system TZ.
If you could also answer the above question, it will help me put light on few concepts which I still skeptical about.

Comment: 4. Same JVM. That's the whole point of Tomcat - or a "servlet container" in general. That should answer 1) yes 2) you can't. 3) is answered by my previous comment. Same as everything else in Spring, use a bean.